# Loguin en un panel en diferentes pestañas con diferentes usuarios

Tags: php, mysql, session

Tengo un panel donde los cada cliente tiene sus datos y puden subir pdfs hecho en php y mysql. Cuando un usuario se loguea se crea una variable de _SESSION con el nombre.
Mi problema es , si es posible, poner entrar en este panel en diferentes pestañas con diferentes usuarios.
Esto es pestaña 1 del navegador entro con el usuario del cliente1 se crea la variable $_SESSION["usuario"]="cliente1", pestaña 2  entro con el usuario del cliente 2 se crea la variable $_SESSION["usuario"]="cliente2", pestaña 3 entro con el usuario del cliente 3 se crea la variable $_SESSION["usuario"]="cliente3". Si hago esto cuando accedo a la pestaña 1 el valor de la session $_SESSION["usuario"] ya no vale "cliente1" sino que vale "cliente3", lo mismo ocurre en la pestaña 2.

Mi pregunta es , hay alguna forma de que pueda abrir las tres pestañas o mas sin que se mezclen los datos?

Gracias.

Comment: Tu duda no se termina de entender ye sugiero leer [ask]

Comment: Creo que quiere abrir 3 sesiones diferentes dentro del mismo navegador, para la misma página. Lo que no es conveniente, ya que el navegador reutiliza las mismas cookies para las pestañas que se abren. - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40801843

Comment: Si queria 3 sesiones diferentes, pero en lugar de usar sesiones se puede usar otro tipo de variables?  Gracias.